# (SASS) How do I exclude my imported files to compile to css files

Tags: css, sass

I have the following sass directory

sass

```
config.rb
-base.scss
-mixins.scss
-main.scss 

site
  -dowmloads.scss
  -messages.scss
  ...
  ...
```

---

This works fine, however I don't want all my .scss files to compile to css files.I just want to output main.css because it imports the other files. 
Whenever I do compass watch all the css get created...
Is this possible?

---

Answer (score 4):

Start the filename with an underscore. You can then import this and it's styles will only get added to the file that imports it. The actual file itself will never get generated into it's own css file.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Solved... Thanks grimmus... :)

Comment: This only works when you control the filenames, which is not always the case -- if this is a Rails project, for example, you may include all kinds of vendor sass or less or css that may include partials.  In that case you may want to use look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/q/34801798/770670